# htaccess redirects (non-www to www, language default select, proper URL rewrite)

Tags: .htaccess

I need some help with properly written `.htaccess` file. I did try my best but it doesn't work always as expected. What I want to achieve is this:

- first of all, if browser requests `favicon.ico`, it immediately gets 404, no exceptions, no rewrites/redirects (my current code still rewrites it, and then returns 404),
- if subdomain is `admin.`, rewrite traffic to `/admin/` folder (leaving `admin.` in URL), otherwise rewrite to `www.`
- check if URL has `www.` in front of domain, even if on any 'subfolder' (ex.: domain.com/en/sub1/sub2/), otherwise redirect,
- check if language is selected (en|sl), otherwise choose default `sl` and redirect
  other requests to index.php in root dir (with lang code included, ex.: www.domain.com/en/example/#selection, ?a=b doesn't need to be sent, I won't use it)

**Current `.htaccess`:**

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

// this works somewhat (still rewrites 2 times... I can see it in apache log)
RedirectMatch 404 favicon.ico
// this doesn't work at all
Redirect 404 /favicon.ico

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^admin\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /admin/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Check if lang. code is provided otherwise select sl
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(sl|en)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sl/$1 [R,L]

# Add trailing slash if not found
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/ [R,L]

# Process virtual links/directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/?$1 [QSA,L]
```

**Problems:**

- when accessing `admin.domain.com` I get `500 Internal Server Error`,
- `favicon.ico` isn't returned with 404 at first instance,
- everything else works, but if you have recommendation on how to improve it, I would appreciate it.

**SOLUTION:**

I removed the `RedirectMatch` rule and just go with `Redirect 404 /favicon.ico`, but in addition I had to add almost everywhere `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !favicon.ico` to get proper 404 response (without any rewrite/redirection).

About admin subdomain: I leaved exactly the same rules, but I have created additional `.htaccess` in /admin folder, which sorts out traffic that gets there.

Answer (score 0):

### admin.domain.com - 500 error

Your admin rewrite matches too broadly which sends it in an infinite loop.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^admin\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /admin/$1 [L]
```

Try adding the condition `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin [NC]` to avoid the loop (it will never match if the *real* request begins with `/admin`.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^admin\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /admin/$1 [L]
```

### Favicon.ico

Both the [RedirectMatch](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) and [Redirect](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) directive has two required arguments: the regex/path and the redirect URL. The status code is optional. Theoretically your rule(s) `RedirectMatch 404 favicon.ico` might be interpreted as "if path matches 404 then redirect to favicon.ico". I suggest adding a dummy url (that doesn't exist) to the directives, ala: `Redirect 404 /favicon.ico /dev/null`.